# _target = blank and window size

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer

My goal is start some page in IE8 in a new window. I'm using _target = blank for it, but start sixe of result window is like 300X400. So, my question is : Am I able to manage size of browser result window if I use _target = blanck ?

UPDATE : I need solution without js, if possible

Comment: you could try to make a `<frame>` old style

Comment: but it wouldn't be a new window

Comment: Is this frame can be started outside current page?

Comment: I'm not sure you are able to do what you need without JS.

Comment: Probably, this is right answer on my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showPopup(url) {
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=190,width=520,top=200,left=300,resizable');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a href='...' onClick='showPopup(this.href);return(false);'>Info</a>
```

Comment: this is good solution but not my case; I need to use _target = blank, in other words, I'm not permitted to use js as a solution. Sorry..

Comment: I think that with only html and css you cannot do what you want

Answer (score 1):

With out JavaScript, it is not possible. So, here is code!

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','nyWindow','width=300,Height=400');">Open Window</a>
```

Hope it helps u...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <a href="#" onclick="window.open('google.com','height=100,width=100');return false;">test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how it's done with JQuery:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
        var windowSizeArray = [ "width=200,height=200",
                                "width=300,height=400,scrollbars=yes" ];

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.newWindow').click(function (event){

                var url = $(this).attr("href");
                var windowName = "popUp";//$(this).attr("name");
                var windowSize = windowSizeArray[$(this).attr("rel")];

                window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);

                event.preventDefault();

            });
        });
    </script>

    <a href="http://www.Zakharko.com/" rel="0" class="newWindow" >open me</a>
```